# AmCharts set displayed Month

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amstock

I'm using AmCharts/AmStockCharts to display a line chart of data that spans the entire year. It's generally zoomed in to display a single month, as that's a useful zoom level.

It defaults to the last month it has data for, however, and I would like to set it to display the current month instead.

Currently this is the Chart's config:

```
AmCharts.makeChart("overview_chart", {
        type: "stock",
        "theme": "light",
        "categoryAxesSettings": {
            minPeriod: "1hh",
            groupToPeriods: ["1hh"]
        },

        dataSets: [
            {
                fieldMappings: fieldMappings,
                dataProvider: chartData,
                title: "Overview",
                categoryField: "date"
            }
        ],

        panels: [
            {
                title: "Results",
                showCategoryAxis: true,
                percentHeight: 70,
                valueAxes: [
                    {
                        id: "v1",
                        stackType: "regular"
                    }
                ],

                categoryAxis: {
                    dashLength: 5
                },

                stockGraphs: stockGraphs,

                stockLegend: {
                 align: "left",
                 position: "absolute",
                 divId: "optimizationLegend"
                 }
            }
        ],

        chartScrollbarSettings: {

            graph: "Total", // shows nice profile
            graphType: "line",
            usePeriod: "1hh"
        },

        chartCursorSettings: {
            valueBalloonsEnabled: true,
            valueLineBalloonEnabled: true,
            valueLineEnabled: true,
            categoryBalloonText: '[[category]]',
            categoryBalloonDateFormats: [
                {
                    period: "YYYY",
                    format: "DD.MM.YYYY HH:NN"
                }, {
                    period: "MM",
                    format: "DD.MM.YYYY HH:NN"
                }, {
                    period: "WW",
                    format: "DD.MM.YYYY HH:NN"
                }, {
                    period: "DD",
                    format: "DD.MM.YYYY HH:NN"
                }, {
                    period: "hh",
                    format: "DD.MM.YYYY HH:NN"
                }, {
                    period: "mm",
                    format: "DD.MM.YYYY HH:NN"
                }, {
                    period: "ss",
                    format: "DD.MM.YYYY HH:NN"
                }, {
                    period: "fff",
                    format: "DD.MM.YYYY HH:NN"
                }
            ]
        },

        periodSelector: {
            position: "bottom",
            periods: [
                {
                    period: "MM",
                    selected: true,
                    count: 1,
                    label: "1 month"
                }, {
                    period: "YYYY",
                    count: 1,
                    label: "1 year"
                }, {
                    period: "YTD",
                    label: "YTD"
                }, {
                    period: "MAX",
                    label: "MAX"
                }
            ]
        },
        "export": {
            "enabled": true
        }
    });
```

How would I do that?

Comment: Can you please share us a fiddle to check your issue?

Comment: I suppose, but I don't currently have anything, not even a partial solution. 
I'm building a regular AmStockChart by loading some data and using makeChart().
So I'm not sure what the fiddle could show?

Comment: A fiddle would show what settings you're using. A "regular AmStockChart" doesn't say much as to what you have enabled because a stock chart doesn't necessarily default to that behavior depending on the properties you're using. For example, a barebones setup with just the panel and dataset properties set will show the entire dataset instead of just the last month. I can hazard a guess as to what you *might* have enabled from the behavior you're describing and can whip up an answer, but a fiddle will certainly prevent a lot of back and forth in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have a `periodSelector` enabled with one of the buttons' `selected` property set to true (most likely the `1 month` button from the AmCharts examples). These buttons always start from the end of your data by default, though the behavior can be tweaked if you create your own [`changed`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/PeriodSelector#changed) event in the `periodSelector`, but that's going a bit off topic.

You can set the default zoom by creating your own [`rendered`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/AmStockChart#rendered) event that zooms to your desired dates by calling the chart's [`zoom`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/AmStockChart#zoom) method. Note that you need to remove the `selected` property from your `periodSelector` for this to work:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  // ...
  "listeners": [{
    "event": "rendered",
    "method": function(e) {
      var startDate = new Date();
      var endDate = new Date();

      startDate.setDate(1);
      endDate.setMonth(endDate.getMonth() + 1, 1);
      e.chart.zoom(startDate, endDate);
    }
  }]
});
```

Here's a [demo](http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/86fe95c59fd0dbfa4199abcc0c41e039?editors=0010).

**Edit**
The [`init`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/AmStockChart#init) event will also work as well and may be preferable depending on your scenario. [`validateData()`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/AmStockChart#validateData)/[`validateNow()`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/AmStockChart#validateNow) calls trigger the `rendered` event, so if you're dynamically adding data to the chart after the initial makeChart call, then the default zoom code will fire as well. If you don't want this to happen, use `init` instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, this has absolutely no effect, even though I can see that it gets called. The type of the event when it gets called is "load", too, instead of "rendered"...

Comment: Are you sure you removed the `selected` property in your periodSelector button like I said? That is the important part of making this work. I [created a codepen](http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/65753a3fb4c8167ff8a6a98d7fbca99f?editors=0010) with your code and it works for me after I commented out the `selected` line.

Comment: One more question, though: Why "rendered" and not "init"?

Comment: Good question. `init` will also work in this case. I'm just used to using `rendered`, so chalk it up to a force of habit. If you're adding data to the chart after the makeChart call and you don't want the zoom to reset to the current month, then `init` is better in that scenario. `rendered` will always fire when the chart is redrawn.

Comment: Actually: On my linux box, this works fine - on my Windows PC I get an endless loop until the browser tab crashes. wat?!

Comment: That is extremely odd. I wrote and tested this all on my Windows PC and I don't have that issue. Can you provide a fiddle that reproduces the error?

Comment: No, sorry - it's part of a larger react app and when I try to break it out of there I must be doing something wrong.

Even setting the event to init doesn't help - it's as if calling "zoom" causes it to start over again.

Comment: So it looks like the zoom call really was to blame. By comparing chart.previousStartDate's month and day to the "new" startDate and only calling .zoom if they differ, I was able to cut the chain of calls and now it works. I have no idea why that is necessary in my case, on Windows only, and not in your case.